# vue remove file array item afect other item's file input

Tags: vuejs2

vue 2.x

i have a file array, each item contains a file input as well as other text input, user can click + icon to add a item and have to upload one file or delete one item.

it looks like following:

[image: before]

however, if i add two items and each item has a file, then i delete the first item, the file input(original second item) will be cleared too like :

[image: after]

that is :

```
Level A  a.pdf
Level B  b.pdf
```

if i delete first, then it changed to

```
Level B no file selected
```

why? how to solve it?

my vue code is:

```
<tr v-for=" (a, index) in eb.attachmentList" v-bind:key="index">

<td>
<select v-model="a.typeId" required>
<option value="1">Level A</option>
<option value="13">Level B</option>
<option value="8">Level C</option>
</select>
</td>

<td><input type="text" v-model="a.description" /></td>

<td>
<input v-if="!a.eaId" type="file" v-on:change="selectFile(index, $event)" ref="f" required />
<a v-if="a.eaId" href="#" v-on:click="downloadFile(a)">{{a.fileName}}</a>
</td>

<td><i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg" v-on:click="delAttachment(a, index)" style="color: red"></i>

</td>

</tr>
```

```
data () {
  return {
  eb: {
   'attachmentList': []
  }

  }
},               

methods: {            

addAttachment() {

var a = {'typeId': '', 'description': '', 'file': ''};
this.eb.attachmentList.push(a);
},                            

selectFile( index, e ){

this.eb.attachmentList[index].file = e.target.files[0];
},               

delAttachment( a, index ) {

this.eb.attachmentList.splice(index, 1);

//and delete this attachment from database
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the key as your index causes problems when updating arrays.

Instead generate a unique id for your items:

```
var a = {'typeId': '', id: new Date().valueOf() };
```

Then set key to `a.id`

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/tg2yr9L8/

Comment: great, thanks! but why it only affect file input if i use `index` as key? it seems that other types, e.g. select, text input, didn't be affected.